# fastest way creating and pointing to a new branch with perforce

Tags: perforce, branch

I've been testing the branch creation with perforce and I have a question:

What is the fastest way to create and point to a new branch in perforce?

I've tried several ways and I always need to do a sync on the new branch and later performing the integrate command, but that implies deleting and redownloading on disk all the files.

Regards,
    Rubén.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a bit of Perforce-101, which will make the answer obvious. When you create a branch you are creating a branchspec (a mapping between filespecs). You are **NOT** actually creating the files in the depot, which is why you need to the sync and integrate.

If you look at the options for the integrate command, there is an option to `-v` that makes the integrate not copy any new branched files to the client. (type `p4 help integrate` into your command window).

The option is listed under "Advanced options..." in P4V.

[image of the integrate advanced options dialog http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e92ccfa04a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e92ccfa04a.png)

This is *fastest* possible way, that I know, to speed up the creation of a new branch.

HTH,